# Are slashes allowed in targets of POSIX Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, posix

I am trying to write portable (POSIX) Makefiles, and [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) has to say:

> Applications shall select target names from the set of characters consisting solely of **periods, underscores, digits, and alphabetics** from the portable character set

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Quite restrictive. I did not expect this.

And what's weird is: It is **explicitly mentioned** that inference rules cannot contain slashes:

> 1. *Inference rules*, which have one target name with at least one <period> ( '.' ) and **no <slash> ( '/' )**

And again:

> The application shall ensure that the target portion is a **valid target name** (see Target Rules) of the form **.s2** or **.s1.s2** (where [...] *s1* and *s2* **do not contain any <slash>** or <period> characters.)

<sup>(emphasis partly mine)</sup>

Why explicitly mention that slashes are not allowed if slashes are disallowed anyway because it needs to be a "valid target name"? What am I missing here?

Comment: I suppose because it's a common extension that normal targets will allow slashes (I'm actually not aware of any implementation of make that doesn't allow this).  But even if they are allowed in normal targets, they are not allowed in suffix rules (I'm not aware of any implementation of make that allows this).

Comment: @MadScientist Good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

In the first place, POSIX explicitly says that "Implementations may allow other characters in target names as extensions," and it is *extremely* common for implementations to exercise that allowance.  In fact, I doubt you could find a POSIX-conforming `make` implementation in use anywhere that does not allow slash characters in target names by default.

Given, then, that implementations can allow slashes in target names as an extension, and that that has special implications on the behavior of `make`, the specification accounts for it in the provisions for suffix rules.  That it forbids slashes in the target names in such rules is moot for hypothetical implementations that do not allow slashes in *any* target names.  It is relevant and important for all the real-world implementations.

So,

> Are slashes allowed in targets of POSIX Makefiles?

In principle, a POSIX-conforming `make` implementation could reject all target names containing slashes.  In practice, all POSIX-conforming `make` implementations accept slashes in target names, except possibly when input or command-line options instruct them to disable extensions and implement strict POSIX semantics.